# Stop images shaking when window is resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize, window

I have a issue related with window resize when I resize window all my images is starting shaking how can I solve this problem ? ...
example here `[https://jsfiddle.net/aqyp18ef/84/][1]`

Comment: please edit and put the js fiddle in a correct manner so we can access it directly

Comment: why you have added 50 second transition?

Answer (score 0):

reduce transition time  `transition: 50s;` to like  `transition: 50ms;`